# Good APIs for scope analyzers

Tags: programming-languages, code-generation, scope, lexical-analysis

I'm working on some code generation tools, and a lot of complexity comes from doing scope analysis.
I frequently find myself wanting to know things like

1. What are the free variables of a function or block?
2. Where is this symbol declared?
3. What does this declaration mask?
4. Does this usage of a symbol potentially occur before initialization?
5. Does this variable potentially escape?

and I think it's time to rethink my scoping kludge.

I can do all this analysis but am trying to figure out a way to structure APIs so that it's easy to use, and ideally, possible to do enough of this work lazily.

What tools like this are people familiar with, and what did they do right and wrong in their APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised at at the question, as I've done tons of code generation and the question of scoping rarely comes up (except occasionally the desire to **generate unique names**).

To answer your example questions **requires serious program analysis well beyond scoping**.  Escape analysis by itself is nontrivial.  Use-before-initialization can be trivial or nontrivial depending on the target language.

In my experience, APIs for program analysis are **difficult to design and frequently language-specific**.  If you're targeting a low-level language you might learn something useful from the [Machine SUIF](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/hube/software/nci/overview.html) APIs.

In your place I would be tempted to **steal someone else's framework for program analysis**.  [George Necula](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~necula/) and his students built [CIL](http://manju.cs.berkeley.edu/cil/), which seems to be the current standard for analyzing C code.  [Laurie Hendren](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/~hendren/)'s group have built some nice tools for analyzing Java.

**If I had to roll my own** I'd worry less about APIs and more about a really good representation for abstract-syntax trees.

In the very limited domain of dataflow analysis (which includes the uninitialized-variable question), João Dias and I have adapted some [nice work by Sorin Lerner, David Grove, and Craig Chambers](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/old/lerner01composing.html).  Only our [preliminary results](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/zipcfg-abstract.html) are published.

Finally if you want to **generate code in multiple languages** this is a **complete can of worms**.  I have done it badly several times.  If you create something you like, publish it!

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response.

Alpha renaming is not an issue in this system.

This is for a system that includes lint-tools for a dynamic language so good heuristic are often workable.

Comment: You're right about escape analysis of course, but a heuristic that tells whether a function defined inside another function might escape can help a lint tool ignore things like immediately used javascript closures closing over too much, or accessing a loop counter that's used in multiple loops.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I will see what I can glean from those links.